# How can i assign a static ip address for an Azure app service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to assign a static ip address for my azure app service , instead of the outbound ip addresses.

Is there any illustrated documentation on how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your scenario description,to obtain a dedicated, fixed IP address for your application, you could set up an [IP-based SSL binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#1-add-the-binding). See, [Get a static inbound IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip)

Just to highlight, on App Service each deployment unit is assigned a set of virtual IP addresses, which includes one public inbound IP address and a set of [outbound IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips).

By default, your WebApp utilizes a shared public IP address. When you associate a certificate with an IP SSL binding, App Service creates a new, dedicated IP address for your app. If you map an A record to your WebApp, be sure to update your domain registrar with this newly assigned, dedicated IP address.

If you want your own set of outbound IPs or need a fixed IP for your use-case, then you may consider App Service Environment (ASE). [App Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/environment/overview) use dedicated network infrastructures, so apps running in an App Service environment get static, dedicated IP addresses both for inbound and outbound connections.